# Unable to Install devtools in R on Jenkins

Tags: r, jenkins, devtools

I'm building a Jenkins Job to test a library.

I'm doing most of the scripts work in the [r-base docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/r-base).

When I try to install dev tools via `Rscript -e`

```
dir.create(Sys.getenv("R_LIBS_USER"), recursive = TRUE)  # create personal library
                          .libPaths(Sys.getenv("R_LIBS_USER"))  # add to the path 
               
install.packages("devtools")

install_allstate_github <- function(user, repo, ...) {
       tmp_dir <- "$app_dir/ravenclaw"

       devtools::install(tmp_dir, dependencies = TRUE)
}

install_allstate_github("SortingHat", "ravenclaw")

library(ravenclaw)
```

I get the following error

```
Warning message:
In dir.create(Sys.getenv("R_LIBS_USER"), recursive = TRUE) :
  '/export/home/compjenk/workspace/ISG-Sorting-Hat/Ravenclaw/r-libs' already exists
Installing package into ���/export/home/compjenk/workspace/ISG-Sorting-Hat/Ravenclaw/r-libs���
(as ���lib��� is unspecified)
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://****:****@artifactory.allstate.com/artifactory/cran/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://****:****@artifactory.allstate.com/artifactory/cran/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning messages:
1: In gzfile(file, "rb") :
  cannot open compressed file '/tmp/RtmpQGoABw/repos_https://****:****@artifactory.allstate.com/artifactory/cran/src/contrib.rds', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
2: package ���devtools��� is not available (for R version 4.0.2) 
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ���devtools���
Calls: install_allstate_github ... loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart
Execution halted
```

I've set the corporate CRAN server in .Rprofile as well as Proxy information but it doesn't seem to help.

*.Rprofile*

```
local({
       r <- list("cran" = "https://****:****@artifactory.allstate.com/artifactory/cran/")
       options(repos = r)
       options(RCurlOptions = list(ssl.verifypeer = FALSE, 
                                   ssl.verify = FALSE,
                                   proxy = "http://webproxy:8080"))
       #set_config( config( ssl_verifypeer = 0L ) )
       Sys.setenv(http_proxy = "http://webproxy:8080")
       Sys.setenv(https_proxy = "https://webproxy:8080")
```

So What am I missing or doing wrong? why can't I install devTools?

Comment: It's curious that R is trying open the file `/tmp/RtmpQGoABw/repos_https://****:****@artifactory.allstate.com/artifactory/cran/src/contrib.rds`. That isn't a valid path.

Comment: @NickODell I thought that was interesting too, but I can't tell what's causing that.  Is R unable to open a Compressed file?  Is my Proxy interfering? Is it Self-Signed Cretificates for Artifactory? How can I tell?  the URLS work fine in my browser locally.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very familiar with R packages. I'm not sure what would cause that. Maybe you can try commenting out everything in your Rprofile except the web proxy, and running `install.packages("devtools")` again?

Comment: When I remove Local Artifactory, it stops at being unable to read `.../PACKAGES`.
I have a python build, that doesn't use the proxy config at all.  I just had to make sure that it didn't verify SSL for the Artifactory connection.